# How to pass multiple components dynamically inside other component react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, components, parameter-passing

[image: photo]

I think my problem is very easy, but I am learning RN and I am stuck. I want to pass
Header, PhotoCarousel, UserDetails components dynamically inside KennelScreen component, for right now I just did it in the JS way. Is there any other way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you want to archive. You could create them dynamically via

```
const KennelScreen = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <ScrollView>
        {React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) =>
          React.cloneElement(child)
        )}
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

Then you can use it in your parent screen with

```
<KennelScreen>
 <Header />
....
</KennelScreen>
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try this one!